# ViewController or UIView should be in control?

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

So I have a `'ListViewController'` that has a subview called `'ListView'`

ListView is the master view that holds all remaining subviews.

Inside listView, there is a subview called PhotoView and inside it, it has a UIButton that toggles the constraints of PhotoView, resizing based on arbitrary values.

*Hierarchy is as follows:*

```
ListViewController <- ListView <- PhotoView
```

The reason I've done this is to minimize the amount of code inside each view, to segment it out.

> My question is: Who should be in charge of the 'resizing' function? My
>   understanding is that a viewController should generally handle the
>   main functions that are inside it pertaining to its subviews.

However in this case, it is being handled inside its subviews subview, 'PhotoView'. Should I use protocols to persist it to the ListViewController? `PhotoView(Protocol) -> ListView(Protocol) -> ListViewController`?

Is this a correct method? Or is there a more efficient way of handling `subview` functions?

Thanks guys

Comment: If the view is not complicated, i prefer controller function belonging to controller. View is responsible for presentation not for interactive logic.

Comment: Just like a view adding gestures, most time the logic is within VC. Of course you can have latest patterns which undergoes fancy way. But if it’s working and simple, it s fine with me

Comment: Thanks E.Coms. Would you recommend having a main view like 'ListView', that holds all its subviews and using a protocol to do the logic in there? Or just removing 'List View' and have the view controller construct all its subviews and handle the logic using a protocol?

Comment: If I were to use the VC as the logic handler? I would have to use a protocol from PhotoView, into ListView, then a protocol from ListView into the VC? Wouldn't I? Or is there another route?

Comment: Can you assign or link button to VC z

Comment: You can pass the parent VC (i.e ListViewController object in your case) object to your subviews classes, then you can call a method of ListViewController easily using that object.

Comment: While opinion-based, good question! My thought is - of course - "it depends". Where are the the constraints? If it's the root view of `ListViewController` (most likely but not necessarily `ListView`) I say they belong there. But if it's **a cell** in `ListView` or this `PhotoView`, it belongs there. Honestly? Resizing is a part of constraints. If you do it correctly, it happens "magically" or "automatically". Particularly if you understand the view & controller lifecycle. Particularly `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. (And yes, again, are you using a `UICollectionView`?

Comment: vivekDas: Pass the VC back through the subviews?

Comment: dfd: The constraints are inside the PhotoView subclass, as they pertain to resizing itself. Inside PhotoView there are two sets of collectionViews which are animated when resized. ListView is the parent view for all its subviews, ie PhotoView including another view called DetailView. I used a protocol to have listView control the resizing of PhotoView and it works.

Comment: Was just wondering if there is a better more efficient recommendation? As mentioned before... using two protocols to get the resizing function inside the VC seems overkill (protocol from PhotoView, into ListView, then a protocol from ListView into the VC). Wondered if I was wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you move all logics into `ListViewController`, everything is very simple as you can assign any UIControl in the VC:

```
 class ListViewController : UIViewController{
       @IBOutlet var goButton: UIButton!    //In the DetailView
       @IBOutlet var photoView: PhotoView!
       @IBOutlet var detailView: DetailView!
// MARK: --
     @IBAction func testCommand(_ sender: Any){
          PhotoView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
      detailView.backgroundColor  = UIColor.red
     }


 // MARK: --
     @IBAction func photoViewCommand(_ sender: Any){
          PhotoView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
      detailView.backgroundColor  = UIColor.red
     }


// MARK: --
   @IBAction func detailViewCommand(_ sender: Any){
          PhotoView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
         detailView.backgroundColor  = UIColor.red
     }

 }
```

You don't need to even know the ListView. Use IB can assign all UIViews , not only direct children, but all subview trees, including UIControls, like buttons and labels , as long as they lies in the scene of same UIViewController and their methods is in the same VC not in other separated views.

If you have the code of views, you can move it to the VC easily. Just one class to control all. If you need to know who is who. Adding `Mark` is enough for small files.